# Display alert if came from url

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I have a contact form located on: siteurl.com/help/contact
When they hit the send button, they get send to a page: siteurl.com/ext/contact/contactpost.php - this sends the form off to an email.

However, after the mail() function, I use a header direct to send them back to siteurl.com/help/contact where I want it to display an alert if they came from siteurl.com/ext/contact/contactpost.php

I currently have this (URL will change so using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']):

```
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/ext/contact/contactpost.php";
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $url ){

    // The user was referred by the correct page, so you're good to go
    alert('Thanks, your message was submitted!');

}
```

echoing out $url gives me the correct siteurl.com/ext/contact/contactpost.php but no alert!

Any help?

Comment: Alert is not a PHP function, unless you have created it yourself, PHP != JavaScript.

Comment: How is this PHP page shown? if its displayed on the screen you could try `echo "<script>alert('javascript alert');</script>"`

Comment: Yep had a massive derp there, my bad! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Alert is not a PHP function this a javascript function (client side not server side)!

**Fix Code:**

```
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/ext/contact/contactpost.php";
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $url ){

    // The user was referred by the correct page, so you're good to go
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
     echo "alert('Thanks, your message was submitted!');";
    echo "</script>";


}
```